# Transform negative regex lookahead to greedy needed

Tags: regex

The task I'm trying to solve seems pretty simple - I need to choose all font-changing tags except for the particular one (AIGDT). I'm going to cut them out in order to simplify further text processing.
I'm trying to use negative regex lookahead like this:

```
Font='(?!(AIGDT))(.*)'
```

But for the single-line text sample:

```
<StyleOverride Font='Arial' FontSize='0,32971'>[</StyleOverride><StyleOverride FontSize='0,21558'> </StyleOverride><StyleOverride Font='AIGDT' Italic='False'>n</StyleOverride><DimensionValue/> <StyleOverride Font='Arial' FontSize='0,32971'>]</StyleOverride>
```

It returns single 200+symbol match ... while I'm expecting two 12-symbol matches (Font='Arial').

I believe this is because the lookahead is greedy.

Can anybody hint me to what is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\bFont='(?!AIGDY')([^']+)'`.

Comment: After fixing misprint aigdT (not aigdY) it works.
But what leading "\b" stands for?
It also works without it..

Comment: "The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a “word boundary”. This match is zero-length." Cool, I didn't know about that one @Wiktor Stribiżew, that's nifty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does `Font='(?!(AIGDT))([^']+)'` work for you?

Basically, narrow down the second capture to "anything but a single quote".

(Full disclosure: On my phone at the moment so I haven't run it, but in theory it works nicely)